# Why my pager adapter won't show anything?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I want to build a pager adapter. I created the adapter and setup it into a view pager, but nothing is showing on screen. Please help me with this issue.
My pager view is still white...
Here is the code:

**Adapter class**

```kotlin
class WelcomeViewPagerAdapter(private val context: Context?,private val listOfCards:ArrayList<String>) : PagerAdapter() {
    
    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object` as LinearLayout
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return listOfCards.size
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.welcome_view_pager_view, container, false)
        view.titleTextView.text = listOfCards[position]
        view.descriptionTextView.text = listOfCards[position]
        container.addView(view)
        return view
    }


    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as LinearLayout)
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```kotlin
val listOfMessages = ArrayList<String>()
listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
welcomeViewPager.adapter = WelcomeViewPagerAdapter(context, listOfMessages)
```

welcome_view_pager_view.xml
code from xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFF"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Food Point"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
    android:textColor="#343434" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please give access your camera so that we can scan and provide you that what\n is inside the food"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingStart="60dp"
    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
    android:textColor="#343434" />
```

fragment xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f8f8f8"
    tools:context=".screens.WelcomeFragment">
    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bicycle"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius="100dp"
            app:riv_mutate_background="true"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Let's get started"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    
    
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/welcomeViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/welcomePagerDots"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcomeViewPager"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/view_pager_tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="10dp" />
    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg_50"
            android:backgroundTint="#3061D7"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Create account"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    
    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg_50"
            android:backgroundTint="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

Some text, Some text,Some textSome text, Some text,Some textSome text, Some text,Some textSome text, Some text,Some textSome text, Some text,Some textSome text, Some text,Some textSome text, Some

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val listOfMessages = ArrayList<String>()
    listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
    listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
    listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
    listOfMessages.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec")
    welcomeViewPager.adapter = WelcomeViewPagerAdapter(context, listOfMessages)
    welcomePagerDots.setupWithViewPager(welcomeViewPager)
    welcomeViewPager.invalidate()


    for (i in 0 until welcomePagerDots.tabCount) {
        val tab = (welcomePagerDots.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(i)
        (tab.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).setMargins(0, 0, 30, 0);
        tab.requestLayout()
    }

}
```

Comment: You should edit your question and post the `welcome_view_pager_view.xml` file.

Comment: Yep, i added it :)

Comment: Please, also provide activity, fragment and their xml files.

Comment: OK,  Its done :)